Iterate two arrays and create new one
I have two Array as mentioned below:
const outerArray = ["apiAccessAdmin", "defg", "abcd"];
const innerArray =["apiAccessAdmin", "abcd"];

I need to iterate both the arrays and create a new one like below:
[{"cname":"apiAccessAdmin","checked":true},{"cname":"defg","checked":false},{"cname":"abcd","checked":true}]

Property "checked" will be true if elements present in both array. Anything not in innerArray and available in outerArray, "checked" property to be false.
I have tried this which is working but looking for some other approach to achieve this:
const innerArray =["apiAccessAdmin", "abcd"];
  const finalArr =[];
for (var j = 0; j < outerArray.length; j++){
  var isTrue = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < innerArray.length; i++) {
    if (outerArray[j] == innerArray[i]) {
      finalArr.push({"cname": outerArray[j], "checked": true})
      isTrue = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(isTrue){
    finalArr.push({"cname": outerArray[j], "checked": false})
  }
}
console.log("Output  "+JSON.stringify(finalArr))


have a look at Array.includes()...MDN

No need for a double loop, use the first array as source map() over it and check with includes if it's in the second one


const outerArray = ["apiAccessAdmin", "defg", "abcd"];
const innerArray =["apiAccessAdmin", "abcd"];

const res = outerArray.map(cname => ({ cname, checked: innerArray.includes(cname) }));
console.log(res)




.map->.includes is effectively a double loop, both are O(n)

This only works as expected, if the outerArray always has more Entries than the innerArray. If the mapped Array has less values, we loose the data for the missing Values in the Array that is being checked with includes in the end

@D.Schaller the output is 1:1 in relation to outerArray. If outerArray has 10 elements, the output will have 10 elements. If it has 0, the output will have 0. innerArray doesn't change during the computation, no data is lost.

@Mulan Yes that is true. I'm just talking about the "edge" case, if OP wants a complete list regardless of which array is longer. But I see, that this might not be relevant from how the question is phrased.

@Mulan https://silentmantra.github.io/benchmark#H4sIAAAAAAAACoWPQWrDMBBFr%2FIRXVjEOK2WMS71AUoXXUZZKNK0FrbHxrIpJfjuJbFMSlpatJk3Eu9%2FnYTtHImdaGiEdyjwkGu2HYcRd7aauEaBRKJ4xF4L0%2FvSWgqhdK1nLbCBdym0cPT2HhFnNkfrIm82h1zzole%2F%2BNW%2FAerGqBZllHjupxEF9oc0gorUTSMN5TCYTxTxKoVnvl2qXPNytls8HYlt1ZqhxksYO6Z7zVdR1po%2BsWxaOhdOTrjMKWxFtia3%2B6bPPNtmchSW9xKzlPnPkOepMbx%2BJqAA0wdeaUyuJvlXA82IJS7T2iNklVmTU82zlJrF%2FAV0jRTi7gEAAA%3D%3D

@Alex, very cool to see the iterative improvements. Break even around n=30 shows just how powerful Set is. thanks for sharing <3

@Alex do you plan to release unminified source code for benchmark.js?

@Mulan yes, currently half way through refactoring

For a real world program, you should use a Set as it provides constant O(1) lookups -


const outerArray = ["apiAccessAdmin", "defg", "abcd"];
const innerArray = ["apiAccessAdmin", "abcd"];

const s = new Set(innerArray)
const r = outerArray.map(cname => ({
  cname,
  checked: s.has(cname),
}))


console.log(r)




Thinking outside the box as per usual...
var A1 = ['apiAccessAdmin', 'defg', 'abcd'];
var A2 = ['apiAccessAdmin', 'abcd'];
let A3=A1.concat(A2);
A3=Array.from(new Set(A3));
for(let i=0; i<A3.length; i++){
  A3[i]={'cname': A3[i], 'checked': (A1.includes(A3[i]))&&(A2.includes(A3[i]))};
}

Testing...
alert(A3[0].cname);
alert(A3[0].checked);

